# 404 on category URL

Tags: categories

I think this is basic but none of the advice I have found seems to work for me.  My URLs that access a category directly have been working for 3 or more years but no longer work since an upgrade and some problem with my server.  [I have tried removing my custom theme and deactivating all plugins, but no improvement].

**WP home page:**   [www.mysite.com/monitor/](http://www.mysite.com/monitor/)   This works fine and shows all posts as expected.

**Select a category:**  If I select a category from the dropdown on the WP home page above then the URL changes to [www.mysite.com/monitor/?cat=102](http://www.mysite.com/monitor/?cat=102) and posts are filtered correctly and displayed correctly.  So that works too.

However, when I go to [www.mysite.com/monitor/category/algeria](http://www.mysite.com/monitor/category/algeria) I get a 404 error.

I have a slug shown in every category in the editor.  e.g. algeria  (my categories are countries)
I have been to the settings permalinks page and tried various things including adding 'category' as my 'Category base'. [In fact, I have tried just about every combination on this page without success].

I noticed that when I was editing the permalinks page just after the error started, an .htaccess file was being created in the /monitor/ folder of my file structure, but this is not happening any more.

Anyone know why this isn't working; whether the URLs including categories are redirected with an .htaccess file or whether this stuff is coded within the WP php files (and if so where).

Thanks in advance for help.

UPDATE: 21-Apr-22

I have now, through further research, established that:

- htaccess is only there to divert certain pages back to index.php or when a custom permalink structure is created (so that has answered that)
- the instructions for permalinks are stored as rewrite_rules in the wp_options table.
- accessing a page directly can be done using the URL mysite.com/monitor/?category_name=algeria (this works with the expected behaviour)

I notice two things:

- The rewrite_rules entry of the database is empty.  It is being updated when i visit the permalinks settings and save but is always blank after save! (i.e. if i manually write something in the field and then save permalinks then the record is emptied, so writing is occurring).
- The category_base entry in the table does change when i visit the permalinks setting and add to that field.

Other blogs speak of the basic rewrite_rules in $wp_rewrite array to include an element like this:
[category/(.+?)/?$] = > index.php?category_name=$matches[1]

If I dump $wp_rewrite I get no rules:

```
[matches] => matches
    [rules] => 
    [extra_rules] => Array
        (
        )
    [extra_rules_top] => Array
        (
            [^wp-json/?$] => index.php?rest_route=/
            [^wp-json/(.*)?] => index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]
            [^index.php/wp-json/?$] => index.php?rest_route=/
            [^index.php/wp-json/(.*)?] => index.php?rest_route=/$matches[1]
            [^wp-sitemap\.xml$] => index.php?sitemap=index
            [^wp-sitemap\.xsl$] => index.php?sitemap-stylesheet=sitemap
            [^wp-sitemap-index\.xsl$] => index.php?sitemap-stylesheet=index
            [^wp-sitemap-([a-z]+?)-([a-z\d_-]+?)-(\d+?)\.xml$] => index.php?sitemap=$matches[1]&sitemap-subtype=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]
            [^wp-sitemap-([a-z]+?)-(\d+?)\.xml$] => index.php?sitemap=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
        )
```

if I manually add
a:2:{s:17:"category/(.+?)/?$";s:35:"index.php?category_name=$matches[1]";}
to the rewrite_rules field in the database it still doesn't work.

So still 404 on any attempt to use the category url.  Any help please?

Comment: Permalinks are cached - have you tried simply going to `Settings -> Permalinks` to flush the cache?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, as I say, I have tried virtually every combination on the permalinks page.  The question is - where are the results of permalink choices stored: in the php somewhere, or through use of an htaccess file?